# How to get the first object (with any ordered by function) of each type (selected by attribute) in Java Stream

Tags: java, arrays, list, java-stream, grouping

Imagine a simple object with 3 attributes:

```
public class Obj {

    boolean toBeAdded;
    String type;
    int order;

    public Obj(boolean toBeAdded, String type, int order) {
        this.toBeAdded = toBeAdded;
        this.type = type;
        this.order = order;
    }

    public boolean isToBeAdded() {
        return toBeAdded;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public int getOrder() {
        return order;
    }

}
```

Imagine I have a List of several `Obj`s, with different types:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Utils {

    static List<Obj> createA(){
        List<Obj> list = Arrays.asList(
                new Obj(true, "A", 1),
                new Obj(false, "A", 2),
                new Obj(true, "A", 3),
                new Obj(false, "A", 4)
        );
        return list;
    }


    static List<Obj> createB(){
        List<Obj> list = Arrays.asList(
                new Obj(true, "B", 1),
                new Obj(false, "B", 2),
                new Obj(true, "B", 3),
                new Obj(false, "B", 4)
        );
        return list;
    }


    static List<Obj> createC(){
        List<Obj> list = Arrays.asList(
                new Obj(false, "C", 1),
                new Obj(false, "C", 2),
                new Obj(true, "C", 3),
                new Obj(true, "C", 4)
        );
        return list;
    }
}
```

I want to somehow filter this list and have the latest `Obj` (highest `order` value) for each `type` that can be added (`toBeAdded = true`).

For this example, the result should be a list with:

- Obj1: type 1, order 3
- Obj2: type 2, order 3
- Obj3: type 3, order 4

I know how to filter and how to sort, but I still couldn't understand how to get the first in each subtype. Is this against `Stream` rules? Since what I want to do is basically parse N different substreams, for N different `type`s?

Here is what I could do so far:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class MainTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Obj> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.addAll(Utils.createA());
        list.addAll(Utils.createB());
        list.addAll(Utils.createC());

        System.out.println(list);

        List<Obj> filteredList = list
                .stream()
                .filter(Obj::isToBeAdded)
                .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Obj::getOrder).reversed())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(filteredList);

    }


}
```

However, this is only doing the easy part - filtering and ordering. I still need to do something like `findFirst()` for each `type`. Is there any way to do this?

Do I have to do 3 different streams (one for each type) and then merge the lists? Is there a way to do this without knowing how many types we will have?
I also read about `collect(Collectors.groupingBy())` but this would create different maps for each type, which I don't want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `groupingBy` can help here along with a downstream of `minBy`/`maxBy`. This would provide a map to look up if the value after filtering is present per type.

```
Map<String, Optional<Obj>> groupMaxOrderByType = list.stream()
        .filter(Obj::isToBeAdded)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Obj::getType,
                Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparingInt(Obj::getOrder)))); //highest order
```

The lookup or access to these objects would transform into something like:

```
Obj maxPerTypeA = groupMaxOrderByType.get("A").orElse.. // similar for each type
```

***Edit***: Or if you were to collect all such present types into a final result, you could follow to access the values of the `Map`.

```
List<Obj> result = groupMaxOrderByType.values().stream()
        .filter(Optional::isPresent)
        .map(Optional::get)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

***Edit***: Or to get rid of dealing with the `Optional`, you can use `toMap` with  `BinaryOperator.maxBy` as a merge function.

```
Map<String, Obj> groupMaxOrderByType = list.stream()
        .filter(Obj::isToBeAdded)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Obj::getType, Function.identity(), 
                BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparingInt(Obj::getOrder))));
List<Obj> result = new ArrayList<>(groupMaxOrderByType.values());
```

Comment: This is going in the good direction indeed. This creates a Map with 3 entries, each one with just one entry, which is the highest `order` value, as I initially asked.
But is there a way to reduce it immediately to a List?

Comment: @pmendesm you can access `values` of the `Map` for that. (`stream`ing and `filter`ing based upon your further requirements)

Comment: I could do it by doing:
`List<Obj> newList = new ArrayList<>();
groupMaxOrderByType.forEach((s, obj) -> newList.add(obj.get()));`
I wonder if this could be achieved with less operations though. Something in the sort of:
`List<Obj> filteredList = list.stream().filter(Obj::isToBeAdded).substream(Obj::getType).sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Obj::getOrder).reversed()).findFirst().collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: Accepted as answer

Comment: @pmendesm Made an edit to the answer as well, to what I was pointing out in the comments. I hope the hints are clear and in the right direction if it's not an exact answer you were looking for.

Comment: You don’t need to deal with `Optional` when you replace `Collectors.groupingBy(Obj::getType, Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparingInt(Obj::getOrder)))` with `Collectors.toMap(Obj::getType, Function.identity(), BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparingInt(Obj::getOrder)))`

Comment: @Holger Indeed, thanks for pointing out. I did have that hunch of missing something there with the solution I'd provided.